# How to create a scope that is unscoped in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, scoping

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(active: false) }

  scope :include_deleted, -> { unscoped }
```

This does not work. It returns the scoped documents.

```
alias_method :include_deleted, :unscoped
```

This does not work either: `undefined method 'unscoped'`

So, how to define a scope that is unscoped?

**Use Case**: Yes, I know I can just use `unscoped`. Let me attempt to explain why it may not be such a great idea. There is a good reason to define another scope that has the same function. The reason is that it makes the code easier to understand and it makes my intention more explicit. `unscoped` does not tell the reader anything about the default scope. It only brings up more questions. If we can define another scope that explains ***why we are using the scope***, then it provides context to the reader and helps them understand the code.

BTW, I saw some related SO questions, but they are old. So this question is about ***Rails 5***. Which makes it different and ***not a duplicate***.

Using Mongoid 5, but I don't think that will change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#`unscope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope):

```
scope :include_deleted, -> { unscope(:where) }
```

P.S. Using `default_scope` is usually a bad idea in the first place. But there are tons of articles about it, so I won't reason it here.

Comment: I got `undefined method 'unscope' for Foo:Class`. But the source code that you linked to should do it...

Comment: @BSeven I don't think it is possible. If you take a look into documentation I have provided, you'll see, it is applicable to Rails 5.x, so it should work just fine. Try it out in console, for example

Comment: @BSeven did you play with it? You can also try using `{ unscope(where: :column_name) }` for any amount of column_names..

Answer (score 5):

To make sure you clear the default scopes, you can unscope the `where` clause like so:

```
scope :deleted, -> { unscope(where: :active).where(active: false) }
scope :without_deleted, -> { where(active: true) }
scope :with_deleted, -> { unscope(where: :active) }
default_scope { without_deleted }
```

I prefer to use a timestamp column called `deleted_at`. That way I can mark the time of deletion. In that case the scopes would look like:

```
scope :deleted, -> { unscope(where: :deleted_at).where.not(deleted_at: nil) }
scope :without_deleted, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
scope :with_deleted, -> { unscope(where: :deleted_at) }
default_scope { without_deleted }
```